# SharePoint Designer Workflow Append/Delegate/Escalate Task actions missing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I noticed in the SharePoint designer 2010 workflow some OOTB task actions options are missing.

SharePoint 2010 Enterprise edition...

Append task, Delegate Task, Escalate Task, Forward task.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although they are OOTB actions, they are not available in every context.

Not too informative, but still accurate quote from [SharePoint Designer 2010 reference guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx):

> The actions available in the category vary depending on your context in a workflow.

Comment: Got it... as you said its based on context... It's available under "when a task is pending" action in approval workflow. i'm in a rush...